# outlook web addin <Runtimes> is invalid child in element <Host>

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

When i try to use the  element in the manifest.xml, I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xot4A.png)

i tried inserting it different places in the xml but nothing worked.

I am trying to use smart alerts to catch an onAppointmentSend event and do something with some extra data that I am showing in an extra pane that I added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>ea4e7ae9-8c1d-4b79-bfb3-82007c220ab1</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>CWW (dev)</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>

  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Research PI"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Research PI desc"/>

  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon64.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.cww.com"/>

  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.8"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MessageRead.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>

  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">

      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.8">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>

      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          
          <!-- Specify the runtime for event-based activation. -->
          <!-- For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch -->
          <Runtimes>
            <!-- HTML file including reference to or inline JavaScript event handlers. This is used by Outlook on the web. -->
            <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"> <!-- /src/commands/commands.html -->
              <!-- JavaScript file containing event handlers. This is used by Outlook on Windows. -->
              <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url"/> 
              <!-- /src/commands/commands.js -->
            </Runtime>
          </Runtimes>
            
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <!-- Task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="apptReadDemoGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <!-- Task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton2">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton2.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton2.Label" />
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton2.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>

      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <!--<bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>-->
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MessageRead.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="CWW Add-in (dev)"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="CWW (dev)"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton2.Label" DefaultValue="CWW (dev)"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Attach Research Provider to appointment"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton2.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Attach Research Provider to appointment"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>

    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: How you tried to run a sample add-in which shows how to use event-based activation? Do you get any errors with a sample add-in?

Comment: What is your host application version? Does it support event activation?

Comment: From the question its not clear which step is failing for you.
Can you follow the steps mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest#configure-the-manifest

Run the sample addin and check if you are getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

The piece from the manifest file which is captured on the screenshot looks good. However, I'd suggest posting the whole manifest file to find any issue. You can find the following sample manifest in the [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest#request-external-data) article:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.10">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <!-- Event-based activation happens in a lightweight runtime.-->
        <Runtimes>
          <!-- HTML file including reference to or inline JavaScript event handlers.
               This is used by Outlook on the web and Outlook on the new Mac UI. -->
          <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
            <!-- JavaScript file containing event handlers. This is used by Outlook on Windows. -->
            <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url"/>
          </Runtime>
        </Runtimes>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                  <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- Can configure other command surface extension points for add-in command support. -->

          <!-- Enable launching the add-in on the included events. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
            <LaunchEvents>
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="onNewMessageComposeHandler"/>
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewAppointmentOrganizer" FunctionName="onNewAppointmentComposeHandler"/>
              
              <!-- Other available events -->
              <!--
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageAttachmentsChanged" FunctionName="onMessageAttachmentsChangedHandler" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentAttachmentsChanged" FunctionName="onAppointmentAttachmentsChangedHandler" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageRecipientsChanged" FunctionName="onMessageRecipientsChangedHandler" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentAttendeesChanged" FunctionName="onAppointmentAttendeesChangedHandler" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentTimeChanged" FunctionName="onAppointmentTimeChangedHandler" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentRecurrenceChanged" FunctionName="onAppointmentRecurrenceChangedHandler" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnInfoBarDismissClicked" FunctionName="onInfobarDismissClickedHandler" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" SendMode="PromptUser" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentSend" FunctionName="onAppointmentSendHandler" SendMode="PromptUser" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageCompose" FunctionName="onMessageComposeHandler" />
              <LaunchEvent Type="OnAppointmentOrganizer" FunctionName="onAppointmentOrganizerHandler" />
              -->
            </LaunchEvents>
            <!-- Identifies the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
            <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
        <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <!-- Entry needed for Outlook on Windows. -->
        <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/launchevent.js" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties."/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
```

You may try to run the sample code which uses [event-based activation to encrypt attachments, process meeting request attendees and react to appointment date/time changes](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/outlook-encrypt-attachments).

Comment: i just shared the xml file above

Comment: It is incomplete.

Comment: Have you tried to run the sample add-in pointed in my post?

Comment: i replaced my manifest.xml with the samples content and got the same error:
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1' has invalid child element 'Runtimes' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1'.

Comment: What is your host application version? Does it support event activation?

Comment: Hi Eugene. I just edited y question to contain the entire manifest.xml file. can you see what is giving the error now?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you install the add-in in Office by sideloading the manifest file?